# Count occurrences of an integer

Tags: popularity-contest, counting

Based on the question [How many positive integers < 1,000,000 contain the digit 2?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669737/how-many-positive-integers-1-000-000-contain-the-digit-2). I'm looking for the most creative solution to count all the Integers from `X` to `Y` containing the Integer `Z`.  `Z` can be from 0 to `Y`.

Every found Integer only counts once, even if the integer `Z` appears more often.
For example:

```
Z = 2
123 counts 1
22222 also counts 1
```

I will start with a really simple algorithm written in Java (because it's beloved by everyone):

```
public class Count {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); i <= Integer.parseInt(args[1]); i++) {
            if (Integer.toString(i).contains(args[2])) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

if you run this with

```
java -jar Count.jar 0 1000000 2
```

you get this as the result:

```
468559
```

Because this problem is not hard to solve it's just a [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest). Most upvoted answer posted by 28th of February wins!

Comment: It's not entirely clear from your post, but I guess Z can be between 0 and inf? Or just between 0 and 9?

Comment: Z can be between 0 and Y. It doesn't make sense that Z can be bigger than Y.

Comment: @OblTobl Do you really want to explicitly exclude the Z>Y case? Why not just have expected output in that case be 0?

Comment: @Cruncher i don't mind! but it's a little bit useless i think ;-)

Comment: Does this mean that `N` can be `123` and it would only match if the substring 123 exists?

Comment: @Populus exactly!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## bash (20)

```
seq $1 $2|grep -c $3
```

#### Usage

```
$ bash count.sh 0 1000000 2
468559
```

Comment: it's funny if the call is longer than the program itself ;-)

Answer (score 11):

## [Funciton](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Funciton)

As usual, since the line height added by StackExchange breaks up the lines, consider running `$('pre').css('line-height',1)` in your browser console to fix that.

Unlike my other Funciton answers, this one does not use any function declarations. It’s just a program. It uses a lambda expression, though — a feature I added to Funciton in December :)

Expects the input as three decimal integers (can be negative) separated by spaces (i.e. `x y z`). In fact, `z` can be any string; for example, it could be just the minus sign (`−`, U+2212) to count the number of negative numbers in the interval :)

```
           ┌───╖
     ┌───┬─┤ ♯ ╟──────────┐
     │   │ ╘═══╝ ╔════╗ ┌─┴─╖             ┌────╖ ╔═══╗
   ┌─┴─╖ └────┐  ║ 21 ║ │ × ╟─────────────┤ >> ╟─╢   ║
 ┌─┤ ʃ ╟───┐  │  ╚══╤═╝ ╘═╤═╝             ╘═╤══╝ ╚═══╝
 │ ╘═╤═╝   │  └──┐  └─────┘   ┌───────────┐ │
 │ ╔═╧═╗ ┌─┴─╖ ┌─┴─╖ ╔════╗ ┌─┴─╖   ┌───╖ ├─┴────────┐
 │ ║   ╟─┤ · ╟─┤ ʘ ╟─╢ 32 ╟─┤ · ╟───┤ ʘ ╟─┘          │
 │ ╚═══╝ ╘═╤═╝ ╘═══╝ ╚════╝ ╘═╤═╝   ╘═╤═╝ ┌─────┐    │
 │         └───────┐  ╔═══╗ ┌─┴─╖     │ ┌─┴─╖   │    │
 │ ┌───────────┐   └──╢ 0 ╟─┤ ʃ ╟─┐   │ │ ♯ ║   │    │
 │ │   ┌───╖ ┌─┴─╖    ╚═══╝ ╘═╤═╝ │   │ ╘═╤═╝ ┌─┴─╖  │
 │ │ ┌─┤ ♯ ╟─┤   ╟─┬─┐ ╔════╗ │ ┌─┴─╖ │   │ ┌─┤ × ║  │
 │ │ │ ╘═══╝ └─┬─╜ └─┘ ║ −1 ║ └─┤ · ╟─┴───┘ │ ╘═╤═╝  │
 │ │ │    ┌────┴────┐  ╚══╤═╝   ╘═╤═╝       │ ╔═╧══╗ │
 │ │ │    │ ┌───╖ ┌─┴─╖ ┌─┴─╖ ┌───┴─────╖   │ ║ 21 ║ │
 │ │ │    └─┤ ♯ ╟─┤ ? ╟─┤ = ║ │ str→int ║   │ ╚════╝ │
 │ │ │      ╘═══╝ ╘═╤═╝ ╘═╤═╝ ╘═╤═══════╝   │ ┌────╖ │
 │ │ │      ╔═══╗ ┌─┴─╖   └─┐ ┌─┴─╖         └─┤ >> ╟─┘
 │ │ │      ║ 0 ╟─┤ ? ╟─┐   └─┤ · ╟───┐       ╘═╤══╝
 │ │ │      ╚═══╝ ╘═╤═╝ └─┐   ╘═╤═╝   └───┐   ┌─┴─╖
 │ │ │            ┌─┴─╖   └─┐ ┌─┴─╖       └───┤ ʘ ║
 │ │ └────────────┤ · ╟─┐   └─┤ ≤ ║           ╘═╤═╝
 │ │              ╘═╤═╝ │     ╘═╤═╝ ┌─────────╖ │
 │ │        ╔═══╗ ╔═╧═╕ │       └─┬─┤ int→str ╟─┘
 │ │        ║ 0 ╟─╢   ├─┤         │ ╘═════════╝
 │ │        ╚═══╝ ╚═╤═╛ └─────────┘
 │ └────────────────┴─┐              │
 │    ┌─────────╖   ┌─┴─╖ ┌─┐   ┌────┴────╖
 └────┤ str→int ╟───┤   ╟─┴─┘   │ int→str ║
      ╘═════════╝   └─┬─╜       ╘════╤════╝
                      └──────────────┘
```

Comment: That's pretty cool! Using a language you made yourself

Comment: @pcnThird: I think Timwi spends all his time either golfing or creating languages in which to golf (see also Sclipting)!

Answer (score 10):

## C#

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Enumerable.Range(Convert.ToInt32(args[0]), (Convert.ToInt32(args[1]) + 1) - Convert.ToInt32(args[0])).Count(x => x.ToString().Contains(args[2])));
    }
}
```

### Example

```
count.exe 0 1000000 2
468559
```

Comment: clever solution! i like it that you did it without a loop.

Comment: @OblTobl without a **visible** loop.

Comment: of course, nice anyways

Comment: It has a bug, `.Range` accepts `(int start, int count)`, not `(start, end)`. I always fall into this trap myself :)

Comment: Serves me right for quickly knocking this up in Notepad... I've tweaked the code so it is now correct!

Comment: Actually it has another bug. It only runs correctly if the system locale is one that uses `0123456789` digits. `int.ToString()` is culture-sensitive, meaning, it would use `٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩` on an Arabic machine :)

Comment: @mo_roodi Go grab LINQPad! ;)

Comment: @Timwi I don't see a problem here, if the last input is also in arabic it should work fine.

Answer (score 5):

### APL (29)

```
{+/∨/¨(⍕⍺)∘⍷¨⍕¨⊃{⍺+0,⍳⍵-⍺}/⍵}
```

This is a function that takes `Z` as the left argument and the interval `[X,Y]` as the right argument:

```
      2 {+/∨/¨(⍕⍺)∘⍷¨⍕¨⊃{⍺+0,⍳⍵-⍺}/⍵} 0 1e6
468559
      0 {+/∨/¨(⍕⍺)∘⍷¨⍕¨⊃{⍺+0,⍳⍵-⍺}/⍵} 0 1e6
402131
      42 {+/∨/¨(⍕⍺)∘⍷¨⍕¨⊃{⍺+0,⍳⍵-⍺}/⍵} 0 1e6
49401
```

Comment: not really clear...but really cool!

Answer (score 4):

### Python 2.7

## Need for Speed

**Explanation**

[image]

**Implementation**

```
def Count(lo,hi,key):
    if hi == 0: return 0
    # Count(lo,hi,key) = Count(0,hi,key) - Count(0,lo - 1,key)
    if lo != 0: return Count(0, hi, key) - Count(0, lo - 1, key)
    # Calculate no of digits in the number to search
    # LOG10(hi) may be a descent trick but because of float approximation
    # this would not be reliable
    n = len(str(hi)) - 1
    # find the most significant digit
    a_n = hi/10**n
    if a_n < key:
        count = a_n*(10**n - 9**n)
    elif a_n > key:
        count = (a_n - 1)*(10**n - 9**n) + 10**n
    else:
        count = a_n*(10**n - 9**n) + 1
    if hi % 10**n != 0:
        if a_n != key:
            return count + Count(0, hi%10**n, key)
        else:
            return count + hi%10**n
    else:
        return count
```

**Demo**

```
In [2]: %timeit Count(0,123456789987654321,2)
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.2 us per loop
```

**Comparison**

@Dennis

```
$ \time -f%e bash count.sh 0 1234567 2
585029
11.45
```

@arshajii

```
In [6]: %timeit count(0,1234567,2)
1 loops, best of 3: 550 ms per loop
```

Comment: This is, of course, much faster, but it doesn't fulfill the question's requirements. `key` can be any *integer*, not digit, between `lo` and `hi`.

Comment: there is still a mathematical solution, though it would be even longer...

Answer (score 3):

## PHP

Nothing original, just celebrating my first post here.

```
<?php

    $x = $argv[1];
    $y = $argv[2];
    $z = $argv[3];
    $count = 0;

    do
    {
        if (!(strpos($x, $z) === false))
            $count++;
        $x++;
    } while ($x <= $y);

    echo $count;

?>
```

Input

```
php script.php 0 1000000 2
```

Output

```
468559
```

Answer (score 3):

## bash - <del>32</del> <del>31</del> <del>17</del> 14 characters + length of X, Y and Z

Thanks to devnull for suggesting `seq`!

```
seq [X] [Y]|grep -c [Z]
```

e.g. X = 100, Y = 200, Z = 20

```
$ seq 100 200|grep -c 20
2
```

e.g. X = 100, Y = 200, Z = 10

```
$ seq 100 200|grep -c 10
11
```

e.g. X = 0, Y = 1000000, Z = 2

```
$ seq 0 1000000|grep -c 2
468559
```

Comment: nice and clear one!

Comment: Why use `echo` when you could use `seq` and reduce the length by 4 characters? (1 for length of command, 2 for being able to omit curly braces and 1 for replacing `..` with a single space)

Comment: @devnull - thank you, and can also get rid of `xargs` and `wc` - and it also runs much faster!

Answer (score 3):

### Python 2.7

A solution using regular expressions:

```
>>> from re import findall as f
>>> count=lambda x,y,z:len(f('\d*%d\d*'%z,str(range(x,y+1))))
>>>
>>> count(0,1000000,2)
468559
```

Comment: You can use `re.findall` in a one-liner by doing `__import__('re').findall('\d...`

Answer (score 3):

Scala:

`args(0).toInt to args(1).toInt count (_.toString contains args(2))`

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby

This is a great example to use reduce!

```
puts (ARGV[0]..ARGV[1]).reduce(0) { |c, n| n.to_s.include?(ARGV[2].to_s) ? c + 1 : c }
```

Input:

```
ruby script.rb 0 1000000 2
```

Output:

```
468559
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python golf - 61

```
f=lambda x,y,z:len([i for i in range(x,y)if str(z)in str(i)])
```

### Python non-golf

```
def f(x, y, z):
    c = 0
    for i in range(x, y):
        c += str(z) in str(i)
    return c
```

Answer (score 2):

**R 23 <del>25</del> <del>27</del>chars**

Just get the right tool for the job. Simple use of grep in R, nothing fancy.

This is what it does: `grep` all instances of `2` in the vector `0` until `10e6` and count the number of results using `length`.

<del>`length(grep(2,0:100000,value=TRUE))`</del>

```
length(grep(2,0:10e6))
```

Result: `[1] 468559`

---

Offcourse you can write a function that takes the numbers as an input, just like it is shown in the example.

```
count = function(x=0, y=1000000, z=2){
  length(grep(z,x:y))
}
```

Now you can call `count` with with x, y and z, if unset (that is by default), the values for x, y and z are 0, 1000000 and 2 respectively. Some examples:

```
count()
[1] 468559
```

or

```
count(20, 222, 2)
[1] 59
```

or

```
count(0, 100, 10)
[1] 2
```

Some here think time is of importance, using this function in R takes around 1 second.

```
system.time(count())
user  system elapsed 
0.979   0.003   0.981
```

Comment: maybe it's quite too short ;-)

Comment: Well, this is not [tag:code-golf] anyway :) I wonder: what would the program look like if it had to take the numbers as input (rather than hardcoding them)?

Comment: Created a function for the unimaginative ;)

Answer (score 2):

### Java8

Using the new IntStream stuff, this becomes essentially a one liner, if you ignore the obligatory Java Framework stuff:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
public class A{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(IntStream.rangeClosed(Integer.parseInt(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1])).filter(x -> ((Integer)x).toString().contains(args[2])).count());
  }
}
```

It can be run [here](http://www.tryjava8.com/app/snippets/52f93951e4b0ded740bd122c), although I did have to hardcode the values.

Comment: Really interesting Java solution

Answer (score 2):

## Regular Expression

Following will count 1's digits up to 49.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "12313451231241241111111111111111111111111111111111111"  |\  
sed "s/[^1]//g;s/11111/5/g;s/1111/4/g;s/111/3/g;s/11/2/g;s/555555555/45/g;s/55555555/40/g;s/5555555/35/g;s/555555/30/g;s/55555/25/g;s/5555/20/g;s/555/15/g;s/55/10/g;s/54/9/g;s/53/8/g;s/52/7/g;s/51/6/g;s/50/5
/g;s/40/4/g;s/30/3/g;s/20/2/g;s/10/1/g"
```

Answer (score 2):

### F#

This solution uses `IndexOf` to search the string, then a little bit of number fiddling to convert the result to 1 if found, and 0 if not found, then sums the result:

```
let count x y (z : string) = 
    [ x .. y ] |> Seq.sumBy(fun n -> min 1 (n.ToString().IndexOf z + 1))
```

And it can be called like this:

```
count 0 1000000 "2" // 468559
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript

```
function f(s,e,n){for(r=0;e-->s;){if(~(''+e).indexOf(n))r++}return r}
```

`f(0,1e6,2)` returns 468559

What is `-->` operator ? [Not an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator)

Comment: Since you are leaking return variable `r` to the global scope, one could omit the `return`..

Comment: Also you can save a char by using a `for` loop. `function f(s,e,n){for(r=0;e-->s;){if(e.toString().indexOf(n)>=0)r++}return r}`

Comment: You can also change `e.toString()` to `(e+'')` and `(...)>=0` to ~(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 63

```js
f=(i,j,n)=>{for(c=0;i<=j;!~(''+i++).indexOf(n)?0:c++);return c}
```

Usage:

```
f(0, 1e6, 2)
> 468559
```

Un-golfed:

```js
f = (i,j,n) => {
  for(
    // Initialize the counter.
    c=0;
    // Iterate through all integers.
    i<=j;
    // Convert current number into string then increment it.
    // Check if the digit appears into the current number.
    !~(''+i++).indexOf(n)
      // Occurence not found.
      ? 0
      // Occurence found.
      // Add 1 to the counter.
      : c++
  );
  return c
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby

Basically I took [Pablo's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/20506/4372) and semi-golfed (38 chars if you drop unnecessary whitespace) it into a not-so-great example of using `select`.

It selects every index in the range `(x .. y)` that contains `z`. This intermediate result is unfortunately stored in an array, whose size is then returned.

```
x,y,z = $*
p (x..y).select{ |i| i[z] }.size
```

It looks pretty neat both syntactically and semantically, although the `i[z]` part doesn't really seem to make sense.

It works because `x` and `y` actually are strings, not numbers! Thus each `i` is also a string, and `i[z]` of course checks if the string `z` is contained in `i`.

```
$ ruby count-digits.rb 100 200 20
2
$ ruby count-digits.rb 0 1000000 2
468559
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2.7, 70 signs

```
f = lambda x,y,z: sum(map(lambda x: str(z) in str(x), range(0, y+1)))

>>> f(0, 1000000, 2)
468559
```

### Shorter, 65 signs

```
g = lambda x, y, z: sum(str(z) in str(i) for i in range(0, y+1))
>>> g(0, 1000000, 2)
468559
```

Comment: I don't think you need `range(0,y+1)` if `range(y+1)` does the same thing.  Also, you can remove most of those spaces if you're golfing...

Answer (score 1):

Using Ruby's `Enumerable#grep`:

```
start, stop, target = $*
p (start..stop).grep(Regexp.new target).size
```

Answer (score 1):

### T-SQL

*If I can assume variables `@X`, `@Y`, and `@Z` are available:*

**With an (arbitrarily large ;) existing numbers table - 65**

```
select count(*)from n where n>=@X and n<=@Y and n like '%'+@Z+'%'
```

**With a recursive CTE - 127**

```
with n(n)as(select @X union all select n+1 from n where n<@Y)select count(*)from n where n like'%'+@Z+'%'option(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

---

*If the variables need to be defined explicitly:*

**Add 58 to both answers -- Numbers table: 123, Recursive CTE: 185**

```
declare @X int=0;declare @Y int=100;declare @Z varchar(30)='2';
```

---

I have no idea how much memory the recursive CTE can use, but it's certainly not going to win any speed contests.  The example of searching for 2 in 0 to 1000000 takes 8 seconds on my system.

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/29676) if anyone wants to play with it. The 1000000 query takes 30+ seconds to run.

Comment: not fast but very creative!

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica

### First way: strings

`x, y, z` are converted to strings. If a string-integer is not free of `z`, it is counted.

```
f[{x_,y_},z_] :=Length[Select[ToString/@Range[Max[x, z], y], !StringFreeQ[#, ToString@z] &]]
```

**Examples**

```
f[{22, 1000}, 23]
f[{0, 10^6}, 2]
```

> 20
> 468559

---

### Second way: lists of digits

```
g[{x_,y_},z_]:=(t=Sequence@@ IntegerDigits@z;Length@Cases[IntegerDigits@Range[190], 
{s___,t,e___}])
```

**Examples**

```
g[{22, 1000}, 23]
g[{0, 10^6}, 2]
```

> 20
> 468559

Comment: Mathematica is always fascinating, even for simple problems

Answer (score 1):

## Rebol

```
; version 1 (simple loop counting)

count: func [x [integer!] y [integer!] z [integer!] /local total] [
    total: 0
    for n x y 1 [if found? find to-string n z [++ total]]
    total
]


; version 2 (build series/list and get length)

count: func [x [integer!] y [integer!] z [integer!]] [
    length? collect [for n x y 1 [if find to-string n z [keep true]]]
]
```

Usage example in Rebol console (REPL):

```
>> count 0 1000000 2
== 468559
```

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell

Two solutions, both <strike>40</strike> 37 chars.

For all versions of PowerShell:

```
$a,$b,$c=$args;($a..$b-match$c).count
```

PowerShell V3 and up have the `sls` alias for `Select-String`. This requires the `@` to force an array if only one value makes it through the pipeline.

```
$a,$b,$c=$args;@($a..$b|sls $c).count
```

Answer (score 1):

### Batch

```
@setLocal enableDelayedExpansion&@set a=0&@for /L %%a in (%1,1,%2) do @set b=%%a&@if "!b:%3=!" NEQ "!b!" @set/aa+=1
@echo !a!
```

```
H:\uprof>count 0 1000000 2
468559

H:\uprof>count 1 2 3
0
```

A bit more readable -

```
@setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
@set a=0
@for /L %%a in (%1,1,%2) do (
    @set b=%%a
    @if "!b:%3=!" NEQ "!b!" @set/aa+=1
)
@echo !a!
```

Nice and simple. Uses string manipulation to check if the variable `!b!` is the same as itself without the third user input, `%3` (`!b:%3=!`).

Answer (score 1):

### GolfScript

I've been trying to improve my GolfScript skills so I thought I'd give it a shot with this question. Here's what I came up with:

```
`@@0\{.3$>}{.`4$?-1>@+\(}while@;;\;
```

This can be broken down like this:

```
0 1000000 2    # parameters

`@@            # convert Z to string and put at bottom of stack
0\             # init counter and swap
{.3$>}         # loop condition: Y > X
{              # loop body
  .`           # convert to string
  4$?          # search for substring
  -1>@+        # if found add to counter
  \(           # decrement Y
}              # end loop body
while          # perform loop
@;;\;          # cleanup
```

Even though it's GolfScript, by goal was more to try to make it relatively efficient rather than compact, so I'm sure that someone can point out various ways this can be improved.

[**Demonstration**](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=MCAxMDAwIDIgICAgICAgIyBwYXJhbWV0ZXJzCgpgQEAgICAgICAgICAgICAjIGNvbnZlcnQgWiB0byBzdHJpbmcgYW5kIHB1dCBhdCBib3R0b20gb2Ygc3RhY2sKMFwgICAgICAgICAgICAgIyBpbml0IGNvdW50ZXIgYW5kIHN3YXAKey4zJD59ICAgICAgICAgIyBsb29wIGNvbmRpdGlvbjogWSA%2BIFgKeyAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIyBsb29wIGJvZHkKICAuYCAgICAgICAgICAgIyBjb252ZXJ0IHRvIHN0cmluZwogIDQkPyAgICAgICAgICAjIHNlYXJjaCBmb3Igc3Vic3RyaW5nCiAgLTE%2BQCsgICAgICAgICMgaWYgZm91bmQgYWRkIHRvIGNvdW50ZXIKICBcKCAgICAgICAgICAgIyBkZWNyZW1lbnQgWQp9ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAjIGVuZCBsb29wIGJvZHkKd2hpbGUgICAgICAgICAgIyBwZXJmb3JtIGxvb3AKQDs7XDsgICAgICAgICAgIyBjbGVhbnVwCgo%3D): Note that I've reduced Y in the demo so that it can complete in < 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP - 112

No visible loops, but a bit heavy on memory!

```
<?=count(array_filter(range($argv[1],$argv[2]),function($i)use($argv){return strpos($i,$argv[3].'')!==false;}));
```

Usage `php script.php 0 1000000 2`

Answer (score 1):

## ECMAScript 3 to 6

(javascript, JScript, etc)

### using regex:

```
function f(x,y,z,r){for(r=0,z=RegExp(z);x<y;r+=+z.test(''+x++));return r}
```

**breakdown:**

```
function f(x,y,z,r){        // note argument `r`, eliminating the need for `var `
  for( r=0, z=RegExp(z)     // omitting `new` since ES will add it if omitted
     ; x<y                  // 
     ; r+=+z.test(''+x++)   // `x++` == post increment
                            // `''+Number` == convert Number to string
                            // `test` gives true | false
                            // `+Boolean` converts boolean to 1 | 0
                            // `r+=Number` incrementing r (were Number is always 1 or 0)
     );                     // no body thus semicolon is mandatory!
  return r;                 // returning r
}
```

### using indexOf:

```
function f(x,y,z,r){for(r=0;x<y;r+=+!!~(''+x++).indexOf(z));return r}
```

**breakdown:**

```
function f(x,y,z,r){                // note argument `r`, eliminating the need for `var `
  for( r=0                          // omitting `new` since ES will add it if omitted
     ; x<y                          // 
     ; r+=+!!~(''+x++).indexOf(z)   // `x++` == post increment
                                    // `''+Number` == convert Number to string
                                    // `indexOf` returns index or `-1` when not found
                                    // `!!~ indexOf` converts sentinel value to boolean
                                    // `+Boolean` converts boolean to 1 | 0
                                    // `r+=Number` incrementing r (were Number is 1 or 0)
     );                             // no body thus semicolon is mandatory!
  return r;                         // returning r
}
```

<sup>this function-body is one char less then florent's, so when using ES6 `=>` function notation the total would be 62 char</sup>

Example call: `f(0,1e6,2)`
Example use: `alert( f(0,1e6,2) );`

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7CHtm/)

PS: both functions above return their *local* variable `r`.
So when leaking the result variable `r` into the global scope, one can again save 10 characters:

```
function f(x,y,z){for(r=0;i<=j;r+=+!!~(''+i++).indexOf(z));}
```

Example use: `alert( f(0,1e6,2)||r );`

Answer (score 1):

#### Delphi - 120

Bit to much for my taste, going to see if i can get some off.

```
var x,y,z,i,c:int16;begin readLn(x,y,z);for i:=x to y do if inttostr(i).contains(inttostr(z))then inc(c);writeln(c);end.
```

Comment: don't mind for the length, i love to see a delphi solution ;-)

Comment: @OblTobl Great, but its so much fun to try make it short :P

Answer (score 1):

## k [28 chars]

```
{+/($x+!y)like"*",$:[z],"*"}
```

#### Usage

```
{+/($x+!y)like"*",$:[z],"*"}[0;1000000;2]
468559
```

Comment: You can save a character by replacing `$:[z]` with `($z)`.

Comment: However, the upper bound of your solution is incorrect. It enumerates from x to x+y-1, not from x to y.

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript - <s>55</s> 54 chars (Loop)

#### (Shortest JS solution!)

Edit: 12/Feb/14 - Updated search condition - 1 char reduced

```
a=(x,y,z,c)=>{while(x<=y)c+=(x+++'').search(z)+1?1:0}
```

Using the new [fat arrow notation](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2012/03/30/what-is-the-meaning-of-this/,).

**Usage:** `a(1,20,2,0),c` gives `3` (Note the fourth argument is compulsorily set to `0` and don't forget the `,c` also. Just some work to save chars ;) ).

#### Javascript - <s>62</s> 61 chars (Recursive)

Edit: 12/Feb/14 - Updated search condition - 1 char reduced

```
c=0
a=(x,y,z)=>{if(x<=y)c+=(x+'').search(z)+1?1:0,a(x+1,y,z)}
```

**Usage:** `a(1,20,2),c` gives `3`

Feedback appreciated!

Comment: @ Everyone Just to let know, I miscounted the chars of recursive version. They are 62 instead of 72 :P Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2.7 - 50 chars

Bit of a saving on the existing Python answers.

```
lambda x,y,z:sum(1for n in range(y-x)if`z+x`in`n`)
```

Using the following tricks:

- Sum can be applied to a generator, unlike len, so use sum(1...) instead of len([n...])
- Use `` instead of str(), which also allows...
- Kill all spaces - see '1for' and 'if`z+x`in`n`'
- Remove the first range() arg by starting at 0 and testing the offset (actually...saves me nothing but I like the look of it better :) )

In action:

```
In [694]: (lambda x,y,z:sum(1for n in range(y-x)if`z+x`in`n`))(0,1000000,2)
Out[694]: 468559
```

Answer (score 1):

## k (28)

```
{+/($x+!y-x)like,/3#"*",,$z}
```

Takes three arguments, like this:

```
  {+/($x+!y-x)like,/3#"*",,$z}[0;1000000;42]
49401
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell (56 code, 16 import)

Thought I'd throw a little Haskell version into the mix!

```
import Data.List
c x y z=length$filter(isInfixOf(show z))$map show$[x..y]
```

It can be shorter if we are allowed to require that z be input as a string:

```
import Data.List
c x y z=length$filter(isInfixOf z)$map show$[x..y]
```

Usage:

```
> c 0 1000000 2
468559
```

Answer (score 1):

## perl [41 chars]

```
print 0+grep/$ARGV[0]/,$ARGV[1]..$ARGV[2]
```

Run:

```
> perl -le 'print 0+grep/$ARGV[0]/,$ARGV[1]..$ARGV[2]' 2 0 1000000
468559
```

Comment: Actually this are 43 needed chars.

Comment: You can remove the brackets () around the range, then it would be 41 chars.

Comment: sorry, my counting sucks. but thanks for the shortening

Comment: @LeoPflug your code doesn't work - try giving it '22' as the search parameter (i don't have enough rep to comment on your post), and also try giving it 1000 as the lower limit.

Comment: Thanks, now it works again. Although I still have to fix the lower limit, damn ... Should have used test cases. :(

Answer (score 1):

**Perl - 44 chars**

```
$x+=/$ARGV[2]/ for$ARGV[0]..$ARGV[1];print$x
```

**Usage**

```
C:\strawberry\projects>perl county.pl 0 1000000 2
468559
```

My first golf with Perl(I'm learning it currently) so I'm open for suggestions! I'd appreciate them.

Comment: Okay, just saw after posting this, that one already posted a good golf with perl. atleast I was close! Will use grep in future since I understand it now after this example. :D

Comment: After some edits I beat the other one golfing with perl!

Comment: After fixing bugs I'm behind again. yey~

Answer (score 1):

## Golfscript - 18

My contribution in golfscript

```
`:i;,\>{`i?1+},,
```

Explaination:

```
`:i;        #Convert Z to string, store in i, and pop
,\>         #Generate range 0 ... Y and then remove values < X
{`i?1+},    #Filter all non-matches out of the array
,           #Count the number of values in the array
```

[Try it here](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=MCAxMDAwIDIKYDppOyAgICAgICAgI0NvbnZlcnQgWiB0byBzdHJpbmcsIHN0b3JlIGluIGksIGFuZCBwb3AKLFw%2bICAgICAgICAgI0dlbmVyYXRlIHJhbmdlIDAgLi4uIFkgYW5kIHRoZW4gcmVtb3ZlIHZhbHVlcyA8IFgKe2BpPzErfSwgICAgI0ZpbHRlciBhbGwgbm9uLW1hdGNoZXMgb3V0IG9mIHRoZSBhcnJheQosICAgICAgICAgICAjQ291bnQgdGhlIG51bWJlciBvZiB2YWx1ZXMgaW4gdGhlIGFycmF5)

Answer (score 0):

### TI-BASIC

As usual, `->` represents the `STO->` arrow:

```
:0->I
:Prompt X,Y,Z
:randIntNoRep(X,Y)
:Z=Ans
:cumSum(Ans)
```

Let's try it out:

```
X=?1
Y=?10
Z=?2
               1
            Done
```

Comment: This does not work. the Z=Ans line will return zero if the number is not exactly the same. It will for example not recognize the 2 in 12.