# Counting Pages of a Book

Tags: code-golf

## Task

Given the page of a book **P** on stdin, count all occurrences of the digits 0-9 in each member of the range 1 to **P**. There is no page zero and your program should handle any number less than 1,000,000. Since putting a constraint on how you can do it is difficult to explain there will be a time limit of 3 seconds instead. That may be too short for some of the answers already submitted but mine runs faster than that so it is possible.

## Examples (plus a list of the occurences):

```
input: 10

0 = 1  (10)
1 = 2  (1, 10)
2 = 1  (2)
3 = 1  (3)
4 = 1  (4)
5 = 1  (5)
6 = 1  (6)
7 = 1  (7)
8 = 1  (8)
9 = 1  (9)
```

```
input: 20

0 = 2  (10, 20)
1 = 11 (1, 10, 11 ... 18, 19)
2 = 3  (2, 12, 20)
3 = 2  (3, 13)
4 = 2  (4, 14)
5 = 2  (5, 15)
6 = 2  (6, 16)
7 = 2  (7, 17)
9 = 2  (8, 18)
```

Comment: "Your program is not allowed to loop through all the numbers and count the numbers on each." So what are we allowed to do? Can I loop through all numbers from 10 to N and add 1 to each count (provided N > 9)? Can I loop through chunks of the largest power of 10 less than N and then loop through all numbers in the smallest chunk?

Comment: @MartinBüttner There are ways of doing it without going to each page and getting the individual numbers in it. So if you were looping through all the pages up to 1000 and currently looking at page 865, you can't just pull out 8, 6, and 5. You need to find another way of doing it. Your method is just a rewording of what I said you can't do. Just because you're breaking the pages into chunks of ten doesn't make it any different.

Comment: Are you saying it can be done without any looping at all? I.e. in O(1)? Because if not, then my question is still valid: where do you draw the line between an allowed loop and a disallowed loop? Do you want O(log N) (in which case looping through chunks of powers of 10 would actually be valid)?

Comment: I think the issue, here, is that the restriction isn't well-defined. Are you saying that you're not allowed to iterate, or that you're not allowed to extract digits, or that you're not allowed to use both at once? Or is it something else that you specifically don't want? The restriction can't be a "I'll know it when I see it" kind of thing, it needs to be clear-cut.

Comment: I tried to update it to be more specific. Basically don't extract single digits. you should be doing some sort of calculation or cache checking or something else instead

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/20487/194)

Comment: @PeterTaylor Definitely related but not quite the same. There's some seriously interesting answers in there

Comment: Instead of putting a vague restriction, you could ask the program to finish in predefined number of seconds, given very large numbers as input.

Comment: @metalim I thought of that but I wasn't sure how much time allot.

Comment: I lowered the largest test case since it wreaks havoc on my computer and I'm assuming others as well when it gets much higher than 1,000,000

Answer (score 4):

### Matlab, 43 bytes

```
y=hist(+num2str(1:input('')),47:57);y(2:11)
```

Example:

```
>> y=hist(+num2str(1:input('')),47:57);y(2:11)
10
ans =
     1     2     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

**How it works:**

`1:input('')` generates a vector of numbers from 1 to the input number.

`num2str` converts all those numbers to a space-separated string (char array).

The `+` converts from char to ASCII codes. Digits are 48 to 57 in ASCII.

`hist` counts how many times each of those ASCII codes appears. Actually the count for value 47 is necessary too, because `hist` collects all lower values in the first bin. So that 47 just intercepts all spaces and prevents them from being confused as zeroes.

Lastly, `y(2:11)` removes that first count and prints the result.

Comment: Do you mind explaining how it works?

Comment: @SirParselot Edited!

Comment: Very clever Luis! But `1:1e9` is a _very_ long / large string! Can you run this for the maximum number of pages?

Comment: @StewieGriffin Thanks! Well, _I_ can't. But that's because I have little RAM in my laptop. I guess it could be done on a modern computer

Comment: I've been running it from 1:999999 and its been going for a while, at least two minutes. However, I am using tutorialspoint online Matlab executor

Comment: You'd need about 21GB, since the number of spaces in between each digits increases for every factor of 10. Maybe one day I'll have one like that... You have my +1 anyway... Really like the solution!

Comment: @StewieGriffin Good point. Actually I didn't consider the maximum `P` in my answer

Comment: @StewieGriffin - Come join us in the MATLAB / Octave chat room whenever you have time :)! http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab-and-octave

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, <s>18</s> <s>14</s> 10 bytes

*Thanks @Dennis for a 4 bytes golf.*

```
qi,:)s$e`p
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qi%2C%3A)s%24e%60p&input=20).

## Explanation

```
qi         e# Convert input to integer
  ,:)      e# Push [1 ... input]
     s     e# Convert to string (concats all numbers)
      $    e# Sort the string
       e`  e# Run-length encode
         p e# Print
```

Comment: `,:)` is shorter than `),0-`. If `[[2 '0] [12 '1]...` is an acceptable output format, you can use run-length encoding ``$e` `` to save three more bytes.

Comment: @Dennis Thanks. RLE feels so obvious now. You never cease to impress me ;)

Answer (score 2):

## K5, 43 bytes (27 without fancy output formatting)

```
`0:"\n"/($!10){x," = ",$#&y=*x}\:,/$1+!.0:`
```

Without formatting:

```
($!10){#&y=*x}\:,/$1+!. 0:`
```

Might not handle all numbers up to `1e9`...(well, it could, with lots of memory).

Also, it's the same core algorithm as the Matlab answer. Ironically enough, I wrote this earlier this morning (before the Matlab answer), but then got distracted by Sonic 06 videos and forgot to post it... :(

Still cool.